# How to automatically send Heroku pgbackups to S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

We use Heroku's PG Backups which has been great http://addons.heroku.com/pgbackups

I'm currently manually downloading the backups everyday to my computer and then uploading it to my S3 account.  Does anyone know how to setup a cron job to automatically create a backup (daily is fine) and send it directly to my S3 account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add this to lib/tasks and have the cron addon running herkou will run this:

```
namespace :heroku do
  desc "PostgreSQL database backups from Heroku to Amazon S3"
  task :backup => :environment do
    begin
      require 'right_aws'
      puts "[#{Time.now}] heroku:backup started"
      name = "#{ENV['APP_NAME']}-#{Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H%M%S')}.dump"
      db = ENV['DATABASE_URL'].match(/postgres:\/\/([^:]+):([^@]+)@([^\/]+)\/(.+)/)
      system "PGPASSWORD=#{db[2]} pg_dump -Fc -i --username=#{db[1]} --host=#{db[3]} #{db[4]} > tmp/#{name}"
      s3 = RightAws::S3.new(ENV['s3_access_key_id'], ENV['s3_secret_access_key'])
      bucket = s3.bucket("#{ENV['APP_NAME']}-heroku-backups", true, 'private')
      bucket.put(name, open("tmp/#{name}"))
      system "rm tmp/#{name}"
      puts "[#{Time.now}] heroku:backup complete"
    # rescue Exception => e
    #   require 'toadhopper'
    #   Toadhopper(ENV['hoptoad_key']).post!(e)
    end
  end
end

task :cron => :environment do
  Rake::Task['heroku:backup'].invoke
```

Comment: There is a Gem which wraps this functionality, `heroku_s3_backup`. Works very nicely.

Comment: Douglas: "Does anyone know how to setup a cron job to automatically create a backup (daily is fine) and send it directly to my S3 account?" Thusly I posted a cron job.

Comment: The Gem is the exact same code, wrapped up so your cron job can be nice and neat. See: https://github.com/edavis10/heroku_s3_backup.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm surprised this isn't posted on the Heroku help docs or blog :)

Comment: I was using this for about a year, and it worked great. Unfortunately it does not work with the Postgres 9.1 upgrade. Apparently `system "PGPASSWORD=#{db[2]} pg_dump -Fc -i --username=#{db[1]} --host=#{db[3]} #{db[4]} > tmp/#{name}"` fails.

Comment: @BSeven yeah the answer is very old

Comment: I wonder if @heroku is sponsoring this solution. Is heroku's ephemeral filesystem suitable for such operation? Is it guaranteed not to break without notice?

Answer (score 4):

I've patched the gem to fix the system call mentioned by B Seven. The regex which grabbed the database params was breaking because the new DATABASE_URL for non-shared databases now contains a port number.

https://github.com/mokolabs/heroku_s3_backup

If you're on the Cedar stack, then this patch should work for you. But I'm on Bamboo and it doesn't work for me because of a version conflict with pg_dump. Postgres is version 8.x on Bamboo, so pg_dump can't dump data from the new non-shared databases because they are all running on Postgres version 9.1.

If I'm able to find a workaround for the Bamboo stack, I will update the gem and my comment here.

Comment: Very nice, you should submit a pull request to the main repo.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO the easiest and fast (10 minutes) way is to configure [heroku-db-backup-s3](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/devsenexx/heroku-db-backup-s3) buildpack. No code need, only adding the buildpack and setup some environment variables and one reschedule.